# In Google Sheets, is there a way to name a cell?

Tags: google-sheets

For example, in a spreadsheet, if I have a cell that has a number, is there a way to name it for other cells to use this name as part of the formula?

Example: With the number `3%` is in a cell, to name it as `InterestRate` or `IR`, and be able to use that in another cell: `= SQRT(InterestRate)` or `= SQRT(IR)`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the Google Docs support page:

To Name a range

1. Open a spreadsheet in Google Sheets.
2. Select the cells you want to name.
3. Click Data > Named ranges. A menu will open on the right.
4. Type the range name you want.
5. To change the range, click Spreadsheet Grid.
6. Select a range in the spreadsheet or type the new range into the text box, then click Ok.
7. Click Done.

For the full documentation on named ranges check [Google Support](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/63175).

Comment: ok, so naming a value (or cell) is by naming a range

Comment: That is correct